# RMSE to compare more than two data samples?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to use RMSE to compare more than two data samples (10 to be exact).
I found this function which is used to compare two data samples the actual and predicted samples of a model. I am wondering if I can use the same or similar function to compute RMSE of the 10 data samples in one go.

```
RMSE = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(datasample1, datasample2, squared=False)
```

Comment: You can pass any number of samples you want to compute the MSE. If it is 10 sample, then `datasample1` should be a list of 10 numbers and `datasample2` as well.

Comment: @Kaveh, I meant by my question that I would like to compute MSE out of 10 Lists (data samples) [datasample1.... datasample10] and each list has 50 numbers.

Comment: Most of loss functions, consider input as `y_true` and `y_pred` (2 inputs) or for your case `datasample1` and `datasample2`. If you have 10 inputs (I don't know how it will be computed loss or distance between 10 values!), it would be a custom loss function, and you should implement the operations yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the average RMSE across all pairwise sample comparisons, then you can use the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

datasamples = [datasample1, ..., datasample10]

# Function to calculate pairwise RMSEs
pairwise_RMSE = lambda x : [mse(x[i], x[j], squared=False) for i in range(j, len(x)) for j in range(i,len(x))]

RMSEs = pairwise_RMSE(datasamples) # RMSE for each pairwise comparison
mean_RMSE = np.mean(RMSEs) # Mean of all pairwise comparisons
```